# How can I edit bevel parameters on a mesh object I created last week?

Tags: edit-mode, bevel

Blender 2.90.1 on Windows 8.1

I created a simple mesh object last week (Plane.002 - default name), extruded it to make a rectangular solid, then I edited one of the edges (CTRL+B) with a nice 3-segment bevel. Now I've decided it will render better with more segments.

Where are the bevel params stored for Plane.002 so that I can change Segments=3 to Segments=7 ?
Can it be edited?

Thx!